# Why does System.IO.DirectoryInfo allow constructing a path ending in form feed?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, f#, control-characters

While writing some property-based tests in F#, I have discovered a very strange behavior of the constructor of `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`. Based on the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), I would expect an `ArgumentException` to be thrown any time I try to construct a `DirectoryInfo` with an invalid path character; and I would expect `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` to be a reliable source for these. Its [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars(v=vs.110).aspx) says, "The array returned from this method is not guaranteed to contain the complete set of characters that are invalid in file and directory names"; but it says nothing about the method returning characters that are not invalid! Form feed ([`'\012'`](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/horizontal-tab-ascii-code-9.html)) is one of these invalid characters, as you might expect; I would expect any kind of control character to be invalid in a path name. And indeed, if I try to construct a `DirectoryInfo` with one in the middle or the beginning, it doesn't work. However, it does work if I put it at the end:

[image: FSI session demonstrating the oddity]

The absolute path produced does not have the form feed in it though, confirming that this is indeed and invalid path character. I confirmed that the directory I created in that REPL session was there, with no control characters in the name. However, to make it even odder, when I convert the DirectoryInfo back to a string, the garbage character is maintained:

[image: Form feed maintained on .ToString()]

Then same behavior is exhibited for horizontal tab `'\009'`, line feed `'\010'`, and vertical tab `'\011'`, and carriage return `'\013'`, but all other control characters are rejected. One would think they would at least be trimmed if they were going to be accepted.

What's going on here? Is this a bug in `DirectoryInfo`, or is there some rational/consistent explanation of this behavior in .NET? (And what other such potholes might I have to look for!)

Comment: Take a look at the source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs and the way it handles trimming "_Trim trailing white spaces, tabs etc but don't be aggressive in removing everything that has UnicodeCategory of trailing space._" and see also the many comments about legacy code, paths to devices, ...

Comment: Incidentally, many characters that would be invalid in file names on Windows are perfectly legal in filenames in Linux. [Only two characters are illegal in Linux filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names): the null character `\0`, and the slash `/` because that's the path separator. *Anything* else, including newlines or formfeeds, is a legal character in Linux filenames. This isn't totally relevant to your question, but it's useful to know if you're doing cross-platform code.